# Ruby Savon binding problems

Tags: ruby, soap, https, wsdl, savon

I am consuming webservices with Savon and the WSDL comes with 2 bindings. How do I specify which binding to use in Savon? One of them is `http` and the other one is `https.` I am trying to use the `https` service.

The information on wsdl

```
<wsdl:service name="ExampleService">
  <wsdl:port name="ES" binding="tns:ES">
    <soap:address location="http://example.com/service.svc"/>
  </wsdl:port>
  <wsdl:port name="ES1" binding="tns:ES1">
    <soap:address location="https://example.com/service.svc"/>
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

How do i use ES1? The code I am using now with savon is

```
require 'savon'
require 'httpclient'
wsdl = "https://example.com/Messages.wsdl"
driver = Savon::Client.new(wsdl)
response = driver.request "someAction"
```

When I am using soap4r, I can choose the binding using the following code:

```
require 'httpclient'
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'
wsdl = "https://example.com/Messages.wsdl"
soap_client = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(wsdl)
driver = soap_client.create_rpc_driver('ExampleService','ES1')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to overwrite the endpoint when creating a `Savon::Client` instance:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = "https://example.com/Messages.wsdl"
  wsdl.endpoint = "https://example.com/service.svc"
end

response = client.request "someAction"
```